# What does it imply if all the eigenvalues of a matrix are all the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What properties does a matrix have if all its eigenvalues are the same? In particular, what happens if all eigenvalues are all equal to 1?

Comment: An $n\times n$ matrix with an eigenvalue $1$ of multiplicity $n$ is called a *unipotent matrix*, while a matrix with a full set of identical eigenvalues is said to be *projectively unipotent*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it means not much in paricular, just that it is composed of Jordan block corresponding to the same eigenvalue. From the Jordan decomposition theorem, we see that $A = V^{-1} J V$, with $J$ having constant diagonal entries, which are the eigenvalues of $A$.

However, if the matrix has all the eigenvalues the same, and is in addition normal, you know that it is a constant multiple of identity matrix.